# :after element with scroll height of parent element

Tags: css

I'm want to give an :after pseudo-element the height of the content of an overflowing UL element in pure css. So I'm trying to get the scrollheight rather than the offsetheight in pure css.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Please see this fiddle as an reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/vvb5sc31/6/

In Text:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
LI {
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 4px;
}

UL {
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;

}
UL:after {
    background: blue;
    content: "";
    z-index: 12100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle looks, right. I don't know what are you asking

Comment: forgot to update... now links to the right one

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uooyfkmo/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<ul>` tag have got 100px of height, so the 100% is 100px, doesn't matter how many `<li>` children tags have. Your solution can be put the `:after` in the `<li>` elements instead of `<ul>`:

https://jsfiddle.net/vvb5sc31/9/

```
 li { position:relative; }
 li:after { position: absolute; background:blue; /*** etc ***/ }
```